# How to balance audio across multiple clips?

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, final-cut-pro

I have a number of clips that I want to uniformly amplify and balance. These clips all include a voiceover from me, during different sessions.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a compound clip of your voice over and then add a Compressor effect onto this compound clip.